# SandCastle Help Builder: Search Functionality

Tags: search, sandcastle

I'm very happy with the output from SandCastle, but I would also like to have some search functionality included in the HTML output, is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

The Website output from SandCastle Help File Builder contains **index.aspx** and **index.html**.

If you display **index.html** then you don't get the search or index options:
http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/index.html

If you display **index.aspx** then you do get the search and index options:
http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/index.aspx

Comment: The woodruff site has been updated since this I posted this answer and so the links above are no longer good examples showing when search/index functionality is and is not available.

Comment: Nice! A new [version of sandcastle](https://shfb.codeplex.com/) (released 4/22/2014) which has search built into index.html and only requires javascript. :-)

Answer (score 0):

According the the [site](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) it is, but I have not looked at how to configure it:

> The website output contains an HTML
>   and an ASP.NET index page with tree
>   view that can be used to navigate the
>   table of contents and a full-text
>   index search feature.