# Sandcastle created html help file cannot be displayed correctly in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, sandcastle

I have the API Help that is created using Sandcastle. If you open the link in IE, it's formatted correctly but not in Chrome.

http://rfmw.em.keysight.com/wireless/helpfiles/n7660b/API/html/a0580445-1978-45d0-b723-6e4f64fed0c0.htm

The search in the Chrome browser also is not working, it stuck in searching...

I do use the latest Sandcastle (2017.12.30.2) and got the same problem.

Anyone have the same experience, and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your mistake. This error also occurs with FireFox.

[image]

A browser check gives some syntax error and it seems to me there is a encoding problem (see screenshot, UTF-8 without BOM?).

[image]

Generate the files again by using Sandcastle and upload. Please check if you have the same error message in your environment.

See also:

- [What's different between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom)
- [SandCastle Help File Builder: Search not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527200/sandcastle-help-file-builder-search-not-working)

Please note there is a [sample link](https://www.help-info.de/help-sandcastle/html/63a7cfa5-7cfa-409a-a236-ccf606f9940e.htm). You should examine the jQuery / JavaSript file in your browser as shown in the screenshot above. Please check my sample in your browser too. In my German environment there are no error messages when using Chrome or Firefox for my the sample.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I think I got some idea from you. If you look at the html source code, the html is using UTF-8 charset (line 9 in my browser?). I don't know how to debug into the jQuery code to see why there is some error. I am still tracing to see if I can go any further. Thanks.

Comment: @Y Xu - see my edit at end of answer text. A thought only - it seems to me this is a localization problem.

Comment: I checked your sample link and no jQuery error. Beside the charset thing, is there other *.css or other components/element... in the html file will impact the page display... I am not very familiar with the html/script... works. Thank you very much. Also, I wonder why there is no other people complaining about the Chrome?