# Is project summary supported in web site output?

Tags: sandcastle

First of all, SHFB rocks :-)

I use the Standalone Help File Builder and Tools to render a web based "help site".
However, the specified project summary seems to be omitted/ignored and never found in the resulting output web site files.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to include the project summary in a SHFB rendered web site?

Comment: Please check the link at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527200/sandcastle-help-file-builder-search-not-working/43053080#43053080 and add some information. What do you mean by 'project summary'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short story - an project summary makes no sense when using conceptual topics only.

When documenting code libraries it is important that namespaces are described. XML documentation comments do not support the addition of summary information for namespaces. However, this extra information can be added using Sandcastle Help File Builder.

SHFB gets around the limitation by allowing you to manually add a summary to each namespace. This summary is stored within the SHFB project so that you do not need to recreate it each time you build the documentation.

Having some namespaces you may want to add a root namespace and comments as node into the resulting compiled help file.

As shown below, you need to set some options and add text:

[image]

[image]

**The resulting CHM file:**

[image]