# Sandcastle Help File Builder publish online

Tags: sandcastle

I just recently started using Sandcastle Builder, I am wondering if there is a way to publish the generated index.HTML to a web host so it can be seen from any browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is possible and you may want to give it a try.

I generated a dummy help including some conceptual topics for [testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43053080/1981088) in other context. So, navigate and open the uploaded files from server [Sample Web Help](https://www.help-info.de/help-sandcastle) and see what happens.

Go to Project Properties > Build and check Website as shown below.

[image]

After you have successfully generated your help project you will find all files for upload. The default is a .\Help folder relative to the project folder.

The following screenshot shows the structure of the generated WebHelp for the link above.

[image]